# my java public static void main(String []args) with a simple println does not work in android studio

Tags: java, android

I've just started app making and Java and i got a simple code like this:

```
package nekocorp.helpdesk;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("It's a me Mario!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and it only shows the text in the activity_start.xml file as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="nekocorp.helpdesk.Start">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Me!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

In an Android app, you do not need a `main()` method like you do in other Java apps. Android uses an event driven model. The first events you must understand are call the "life cycle methods". These are used during different phases of your program, such as creating and destroying it. I suggest you start with [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) to help you understand this important part of Android programming.

In addition, there is no "console" where `println()` can display messages. Instead, you must create a Graphical User Interface (GUI) with different elements that define the look of your app. When you create a new project in Android Studio, select the "Empty Activity" to see an example of an app with a simple "Hello, Android" message.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your

`public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("It's a me Mario!");
    }`

In android development, you only need `onCreate()`, `static void main` is for pure Java applications. so try the following instead:

```
package nekocorp.helpdesk;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("It's a me Mario!");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although you could call your static main method from onCreate(), it seems you even didn't read the docs.
Your Activity has a [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). onCreate() is one of the lifecycle methods that gets called if your activity is about to start. So your coding should start here (for the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Android, you don't need to define a `main()` function. You have the `onCreate()` one instead, which is always invoked when the actual Activity starts.

So instead of writing the code inside your main() function, write it all inside the onCreate() and remove the main.

I recommend you to [take a look](http://goo.gl/cYmNjx) to Android's Activity Cycle so you can understand what methods are called during the execution of an Android Activity and when are they being called.