# Java class file not compiling or running on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, module

Where I try to run code in Android studio, its not working and displaying error attached below. example:

```
package com.example.jerry;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Got error when running Java class Test.class. This is the error displaying:

```
5:06:58 PM: Executing task 'Test.main()'...

Executing tasks: [Test.main()] in project G:\JavaProject\Jerry


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\Shakil\AppData\Local\Temp\Test_main__1.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:Test.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 271ms

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5:06:58 PM: Task execution finished 'Test.main()'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my java public static void main(String \[\]args) with a simple println does not work in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516598/my-java-public-static-void-mainstring-args-with-a-simple-println-does-not-wo)

Comment: No its not. I'm creating a separate java class and its not running. (main activity java is ok).